# Git - Automatic deployment in live webserver,doesnot show changes in gitlab

Tags: git, deployment, repository, gitlab, live

I am using gitlab as central repository. Now i am trying automatic deployment in live webserver using this tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

It works fine. When i push my changes it is directly sent the files to webserver. But i need to see the commits, changes in gitlab repo too. Am not very good at git. Please help me if i did something wrong in automatic deployment.

Thanks in advance